# How to avoid detected using proxy, vpn in puppeteer

Tags: proxy, puppeteer, vpn

When i try to check in https://ipsaya.com/ when running puppeteer with proxy or vpn It indicated that I was using vpn/proxy, which said that I was hiding my real ip

how to handle this?

Need to be undetected using VPN/proxy on my puppeteer ?